# How do I get the currency used in a transaction in Google Analaytics Data API?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-sdk

I'm implementing GA4 since UA will stop processing shortly. We heavily rely on downloading report data and I'd like to simply retrieve the `transactionId` and the `currency` of a conversion, for example.

It looks like getting the `transactionId` is not a problem... but `currency` doesn't seem to be an available dimension? How's it possible? Maybe I'm missing something.

[API Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema)

I can use all the dimensions and metrics I find in this other page in the "Explorations" page though, and the currency used for the transaction seems to be available there, under the Ecommerce category.

[[GA4] Analytics dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9143382)

Any idea how I can retrieve the currency of a purchase event?

Will we be able to keep using the old APIs after July 1? I don't see how we're going to get all the information we currently process otherwise.

Comment: I guess the currency is following the setting from the GA4 property admin. It will not display other currency even if you send other currency.  All the revenue will be process to the currency you setting.